# the state is undefined in components although I use mapGetters to access it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a store and a component. In my component and in `created()` I do an API fetch so my state changes and also in `computed` I use `mapGetters` so I could have access to my state. But when I do this nothing renders on the screen. I even use `v-if` directive to see if the value is undefined or not.
Also I should mention that in Vue devtools I can clearly see that the state updates correctly and I can see that the data is being fetch from API.
I already searched so much on the web and tried whatever I could find. Just one solution worked and it was to also have data inside my component but this solution is not a good solution due to duplication of the data (one local to component and one on the store).
So here is my code:

**movies.js (store)**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
  heading: '',
  movies: [],
};

const getters = {
  getMovies: (state) => state.movies,
  getHeading: (state) => state.heading,
};

const actions = {
  async fetchTopRatedMovies({ commit }) {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${process.env.VUE_APP_THEMOVIEDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`
    );

    commit('setMovies', res.data.results);
    commit('setHeading', 'Top Rated Movies');
  },
};

const mutations = {
  setMovies: (state, movies) => (state.movies = movies),
  setHeading: (state, heading) => (state.heading = heading),
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

**Movies.vue (component)**

```
<template>
  <div v-if="!heading || !movies">
    <Spinner />
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <h5 class="center">{{ heading }}</h5>
    <div v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.id">
      <p>{{ movie.title }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'Movies',

  components: {
    Spinner,
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['fetchTopRatedMovies']),
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getMovies', 'getHeading']),
  },

  created() {
    this.fetchTopRatedMovies();
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

One way to solve it is to change `computed` to:

```
    computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      heading: 'getHeading',
      movies: 'getMovies',
    }),
  },
```

but I wonder why this has to be like this. Because in the documentation it is written as I did in the code above.

Comment: Everything you're showing seems right. Could you update with how you're registering the store? Also, clarify if your store is the main store or a store module. Another thing to look at is the actual response from the API. Have you checked the call is made? Is your key valid, is the response what you expect it to be?

Comment: You are using `<div v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.id">`, but in your original code you have not defined `movies`. Which code is being used? Otherwise, it should be `<div v-for="movie in getMovies" :key="movie.id">`

Comment: Also, I also struggle with Vuex getters. They rarely work for me... For this reason, I usually just write the computed to pull from the store directly. `computed:{ movies() { return this.$store.state.movies; } }`. Getters should work, but not sure why they don't always update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    heading: 'getHeading',
    movies: 'getMovies',
  }),
},
```

The above code is working and the reason is, in your condition you are using `v-if="!heading || !movies"` as well as you are assigning values to variables `headings` and `movies` in the computed properties.

But when you use code like below mentioned, as the varaibles you are using in your condition, are not declared in your app so it is not working.

If you want to write the code like below, you can directly use these getter properties `getMovies` and `getHeading` in your app (like you use data properties). So in this case in your condition if you write like `v-if="!getHeading|| !getMovies"` then it will work.

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['getMovies', 'getHeading']),
},
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I taught that by just doing that the vriables would be accessible but I was wrong.